# Error in PHP mySQL query untraceable

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1064

The following code is executing perfectly but there is a mySQL error somewhere that is producing an error message.

```
 $sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = $user_pwd WHERE email = '$user_email' AND authkey = '$user_authkey'");

 if(!mysql_query($sql,$config_connect))
 {
      echo $error .= 'The reset key did not match or has expired';
 }
 else
 {
      $approve = 1;
      $command .= '<div>Your password has been reset.</div>';
 }
```

The error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '1' at line 1

Comment: Have you tried echoing the SQL to see what's being generated?

Comment: I suspect that you might want to wrap `$user_pwd` in apostrophes in your update statment, unless your password field is numeric, anyway.

Comment: Looks like `$user_pwd` has a space in it (it's not in quotes in your query). And I hope you are hashing the passwords somewhere.

Comment: SET password = '$user_pwd' perhaps, with quotes.  Also I'd echo the SQL and try "running" it manually through mysql-workbench or whatever query tool you use.

Comment: first run this query in phpmyadmin

Comment: Not related, but please oh please use `mysql_real_escape_string()` around $user_pwd, $user_email, $user_authkey if you insist on using `mysql_query()` instead of PDO. If you haven't already cleaned your input, you're at risk for sql injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Password is a restricted keyword in MySQL, quote it in your query.

This:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = $user_pwd WHERE email = '$user_email' AND authkey = '$user_authkey'");
```

Should be:

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `password` = '$user_pwd' WHERE email = '$user_email' AND authkey = '$user_authkey'");
```

And unless you are passing quotes in your $user_pwd you need to quote that string in you query as well.

If at all possible change that field name in your database to save yourself some nightmarish debugging in the future.

Answer (score 4):

I hope your using `mysql_real_escape_string` somewhere in the code. Also although not directly relating to the question the mysql extension is discouraged. If your not maintaining legacy code you should switch to [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

I would rewrite it like this and then you can print $sql and run it yourself to get a better idea what's going wrong (note the quotes around password).

```
$sql = sprintf("UPDATE users SET `password`='%s' WHERE email='%s' AND authkey = '%s'", $user_pwd, $user_email, $user_authkey);
$result = mysql_query($sql,$config_connect);

if (!$result) {
    echo $error .= 'The reset key did not match or has expired';
} else { 
    $approve = 1;
    $command .= '<div>Your password has been reset.</div>';
}
```

Comment: +1 for switching to PDO or MySQLi. I don't know what tutorials people use, but I've seen so many beginners starting out with the `mysql_*` functions, despite their security flaws and status as deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You should quote $user_pwd : '$user_pwd'

Answer (score 0):

perhaps i found it.

use apostrophs for $user_pwd > '$user_pwd'

i would try it on sql editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET password = '$user_pwd' WHERE email = '$user_email' AND authkey = '$user_authkey'");
```

You should put $user_pwd in quotes, as password must be a string field, and query is trying to assign a integer value to this field, thats why syntax error is thrown. Try this modification.

Comment: @RobinKnight : please echo the query, so that you can debug what query is being executed in mysql.